# Centos6 libcurl 7.19 POST multi_perform intermittent failure

Tags: c, network-programming, libcurl

I've been having a frustrating issue on specific versions of libcurl. In my application I form my curl request by setting the following attributes via `curl_easy_setopt`

`CURLOPT_URL
CURLOPT_VERBOSE
CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER
CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE
CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION
CURLOPT_WRITEDATA
CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION
CURLOPT_HEADERDATA
CURLOPT_POST
CURLOPT_READFUNCTION
CURLOPT_READDATA`

Without an identifiable pattern I notice that sometimes my request is successful and sometimes it fails where the request is made but no post data is sent. I've tried debugging through libcurl and all I've been able to pinpoint is that my CURLOPT_READFUNCTION is never called in the failure case. I just don't know what causes this failure.

Also, regardless of a successful or failed POST request libcurl will always return CURLE_OK which makes debugging all the more difficult.

Comment: 7.19.x is a *very* old version and you should probably just upgrade as the problem has most likely already been fixed!

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. Unfortunately the product I'm working on Apache HAWQ/Pivotal HDB is certified to run on Rhel 6 which ships with libcurl 7.19 by default so we're trying not to ship our own version of libcurl